# Limit one vote per day in MERN stack appliction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, voting-system

I am using the MongoDB database and node.js as the backend. I want to implement a voting system where a user after logging in to my website and can vote on certain things. But I want to make sure that they can make only one vote per day. How can I implement this?

A possible solution that I thought of:-

Store the latest vote timestamp and then check when he tries to vote again weather a day has passed or not. But this is not perfect as it means there should be a gap of 24 hrs between two votes irrespective of the time of the day he votes in.

Could someone suggest something better than I can implement in node.js and MongoDB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Store the latest vote timestamp and then check when he tries to vote again weather a day has passed or not." If you're storing a timestamp, surely you can compare whether there's a difference of over 24 hours to the current time.

Comment: Yes, but suppose he opens to vote at 10 am every day, but if one day he delays by 10 min then all the following day he would have to make a delay of 10 min then.

Answer (score 0):

Id use Redis with ttl for this and on a middleware I would check if the user already voted(exists in the Redis).
But if you dont use Redis you can also use TTL on mongoDB, so Id create a schema for this and check on every request in middleware.

Comment: I wouldn't add another piece of infrastructure for this. Also, why a middleware? It would be enough to check just before saving a new vote...

Comment: I dont know how he implement the vote system, if he uses few routes/? how can you be so sure?

Comment: It's a simple app, its just has a few API. I am not using Redis, and I don't know much about TTL. Can you brief me on that? Sorry, I am a beginner.